# How can I make this algorithm repeat over different values of dx,dy and store the values in an array

Tags: arrays, numpy, for-loop, brute-force

[image: the image]

I want to the same algorithm to repeat over a range of DX, DY values instead of me setting the values inside the translate function.

The image I used is a simple binary image of an abstract shape. I want an array of distances which are calculated over different values of dx,dy

I believe what I am trying to do is some form of brute force in order to find the most optimum dx,dy that gives the best distance

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from scipy.spatial import distance
import scipy.misc
im = scipy.misc.imread(r'C:\Users\mbore\Pictures\irregular1.png', flatten=False, mode='L')


def ellipse(x, y):
    value = (x*x) + (y*y)/3
    if (value >= 600):
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

def translate(x, y):
    DX = 45
    DY = 75
    return (x- DX, y - DY)

def rotate(x, y):
    theta = np.radians(45)
    matrix = np.array([[np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)], [np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]])
    return np.dot(matrix, (x,y))

data = np.zeros((100,100))

for i in range(0, 100):
    for j in range(0, 100):
        (x, y) = translate(i,j)
        (x, y) = rotate(x, y)
        data[i,j] = ellipse(x, y)
        #np.append(data,ellipse(x,y))


plt.imshow(data, cmap="gray")
plt.show()


plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()

counter = 0 #tracking white
counter1 = 0 #tracking black 

#getting the dimensions of the image -> y
yDim = im.shape[0]

#getting the dimensions of the image -> x
xDim = im.shape[1]

for i in range(yDim):
    for j in range (xDim): 
        if np.any(im[i,j]) == 0:
            counter += 1
        else: 
            counter1 += 1

#initialize empty array this array will receive all the white pixels 
a = np.empty([100,100])

for i in range(yDim):
    for j in range (xDim): 
        if np.any(im[i,j]) == 0:
            np.append(a,im[i,j],axis=None)

#spatial distance 
a = a.flatten()
data = data.flatten()

distance = distance.hamming(data,a)
print (distance)
```

Comment: Please describe your problem: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want to make iterations of the above algorithm over different DX,DY values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand you question fully (and maybe you could ask it more generally as for instance the plotting part has nothing to do with the core problem) but if you just want to run that code for different parameters you could expand your function to generall `DX` and `DY`:

```py
def translate(x, y, DX, DY):
    return (x- DX, y - DY)

DX_DY_list = [(1,1),(2,3),(3,4)]

for DX, DY in DX_DY_list:

    result  = translate(1, 2, DX, DY)               
    print(result)
```

a other (bit more advance) way would be to general you code and using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) as I find it a very useful tool for parameter studies.